# How self works when using it in the initialize and other class methods?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, self

I am Learning ruby and the concept of `self` is very confusing to me in this example.

```
class Alpha
    def initialize
        self.A
    end

    def self.A
        puts "A"
    end 

    def self.B 
        self.A
        puts "B"
    end
end
```

that when I tried to create a new instance from the class `Alpha`

```
Alpha.new
```

I got `NoMethodError` but when I called `B` method, it executed normally.

```
Alpha.B
# A
# B
#=>nil
```

Comment: `self` in the method signature makes the method  a class instance method of the class e.g. callable via `Alpha.A`  . In initialize you are trying to call an instance method `A` on an instance of the class `Alpha` this signature would simply be `def A`. Having said that your method names should be lower case

Comment: Perhaps the detail you’re missing is that initialize is an instance method, not a class method. Self inside initialize is the instance of Alpha. You can call class methods from there, tho, you just need to name the class and call the method as ‘Alpha.A’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the class `Alpha` as follows.

```
class Alpha
  puts "self in Alpha = #{self}"

  def a
    puts "self in a = #{self}"
  end

  def Alpha.b
    puts "self in b = #{self}"
  end 

  def Alpha.c 
    puts "self in c = #{self}"
  end
end
  # self in Alpha = Alpha
```

We have one instance method, `Alpha#a` and two class methods, `Alpha::b` and `Alpha::b`. (Referencing instance and class methods that way is a Ruby convention, one you will see all the time in the docs.)

```
Alpha.methods(false)
  #=> [:c, :b] 
Alpha.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:a]
```

See [Object::methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) and [Module#instance_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods), noting the implications of including the argument `false`.

Instance methods are invoked on instances of the class; class methods are invoked on the class.

```
alpha = Alpha.new
  #=> #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08> 
alpha.a
  # self in a = #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08>
```

```
Alpha.b
  # self in b = Alpha
Alpha.c
  # self in c = Alpha
```

What if we try to invoke an instance method on the class or a class method on an instance?

```
Alpha.a
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `a' for Alpha:Class)
alpha.b
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `b' for #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08>)
```

We would normally write the class as follows.

```
class Alpha
  def a
    puts "self in a = #{self}"
  end

  def self.b
    puts "self in b = #{self}"
  end 

  def self.c 
    puts "self in c = #{self}"
  end
end
```

Within the class definition `self` is `Alpha`, which is why the two ways of writing the class are equivalent. The only reason for using `self` is that if we decide to later change the name of the class to `Beta` we won't have to change all the `Alpha`'s to `Beta` in the class method definitions.

If we want to invoke the class method `Alpha::b` from the instance method `Alpha#a` we must change the latter as follows:

```
class Alpha
  def a
    puts "self in a = #{self}"
    self.class.b
  end
end

alpha.a
  # self in a = #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08>
  # self in b = Alpha
```

Here `self.class` returns `Alpha`, and we know what `Alpha.b` returns.

Let's change `Alpha#a` once again and add a second instance method:

```
class Alpha
  def a
    puts "self in a = #{self}"
    d
  end

  def d
    puts "self in d = #{self}"
  end
end

alpha.a
  # self in a = #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08>
  # self in d = #<Alpha:0x000059c5ff614f08>
```

I could have written:

```
  def a
    puts "self in a = #{self}"
    self.d
  end
```

but `self.` is not necessary and generally is not included. The reason is that when a method has no explicit receiver, as `d` in:

```
def a
  puts "self in a = #{self}"
  d
end
```

`self` becomes the *default receiver*. We know from the discussion above that within the instance method definition `self` equals the instance `alpha`.

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` operates in the instance context, not class context. If you want to call class method, you need to `self.class.A`. Or you can try to go e bit more crazy and overwrite class `new` method:

```
class Alpha
  def self.new
    self.A
    super # this actually calls initialize after object is created
  end

  [...]
end
```